# How to find the best fitting regression equations

Tags: r, statistics, static-methods

I have a very large dataset consisting of car insurance policyholders (C) and those who died in a car accident (D). The dataset includes different rate types (what type of insurance was in place). I want to do a logistic regression as a function of age. Is there a way to find an optimal regression equation?

for example now i have something like this in R

```
glm( cbind(D, C-D)~d_regr+1, data=data, family=binomial)
```

where d_regr is something like age, (age^2), (age^3)/3 and so on.

is there a nice way to find an optimal function, only depending on the variable age - for example with maximizing the pseudo `R^2` or so?

Comment: I suggest using a non-parametric approach (i.e., a smoother). See package mgcv.

Comment: so you mean instead of glm?

Comment: Is your goal to understand which factors influence insurance policyholders and/or car accidents? Or simply predicting these dependent variables?

Comment: simply to predict them

Comment: i want to predict some sort of "accident weights"